# How do I solve the problem with my code that gives me a compile error?

Tags: excel, vba

This is an original code that I'm working on and I am making some changes to it.I added in

```
 lColumnCount = objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).UsedRange.Column.Count

 For j = 1 To lColumnCount - 1
       If objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells.Value >= 500000 Then

 End If
  Next j
```

When I tried to run it I got an compile error message for the 'end if" above "next j".

Is there a problem with the way I wrote it or is the amended code itself wrong?
I'm not entirely sure of what the problem is, nor do I know what does the compile error implies.

Comment: Start with `option Explicit`. Try to compile and fix your variables - also, `objWorkbook`?

Comment: Why do have **`""`** Quotation marks?

Comment: @urdearboy what do you mean by start with option explicit? and fix my variable? objworkbook is the name of the workbook where the data will be in I guess

Comment: @0m3r oops mistake on my part, anyways I just wanna say that those are the "parts" that I added in

Comment: I just formatted your code. And by formatting it correctly you can see that you are missing `Next i` I have provided the answer below

Comment: In the third row there should be **Columns.Count** with an **s**.and you are missing the **Next i** between the last two **End If**-s. What should this be doing: **Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange**?

Comment: I picked that up as soon as I saved my answer to. Good catching

Comment: @anonymous_user the error wasnt with your code you were adding in, it was an error of you simply missing th logic. Please ensure you upvote/mark answers. Cheers.

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried deleting it, there are still errors.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I added in the s but it didn't work as well. There is next i below but I didnt add it in as I didnt amend that part

Comment: @alowflyingpig There is actually next i and next d and etc after that but I didn't include it as I didn't amend that part, apologies. I'm not sure how to show you as the code would be too long to be included in comments, any way where I am able to show you?

Comment: well that's your problem then, you cant nest the `next i` outside of the loop from where you started it.. you could post up the code but <snip> the unwanted bits

Comment: @alowflyingpig in the original code, after the "for" part there are a few more "next". But even after I followed your advice to nest the rest of the "next" inside the extra loop that I created, it suddenly says compile error: next without for. It was fine earlier? So sorry I am a beginner in VBA and am not that good at it

Comment: Every `For` must have a `Next`. Every `If` must have an `End If` See how I editted the code below so you can see the steps ie. `For j`, `If` etc etc, then look vertically down you will see a corrsponding ending statment (end if, Next etc). Just make sure your code is formatted corretly follow the logic and you should find where you are going wrong. Or, just use pastebin.com lol

Comment: You can edit your question and then add the whole code. There is an Edit link below your question. There are obviously more mistakes in the code.

Comment: @alowflyingpig I kinda get it now, but I still not sure where to put the "next" for the "for" that I added in. No matter where I put there is still an error

Comment: @VBasic2008 I have included most of the code inside excluding net paid, claims count and claims count(threshold) as the word count is too much. But other than the part that I amended, there shouldn't be any other problems as the original code before amendment was prepared beforehand and it was able to produce the desired results before

Comment: @anonymous_user I have reviewed your code and updated the format. As you can see now your "blocks" are easily viewable, you can see where you need an opening statment and closing. Combine the 2 answers (as the code was too long for 1 answer) and give that a go. If you still get an error, please detail the exact line by clicking `debug` when the error pops up. Without knowing where the erro is we cant provide any further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Triangle_Monthly_Motor()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim PATH As String
    Dim lRowCount As Long
    Dim cumulative1, cumulative2, cumulative3, cumulative4 As Double
    Dim cumulative5, cumulative6, cumulative7, cumulative8 As Double
    Dim umulative9, cumulative10, cumulative11, cumulative12 As Double
    Dim CUMTOTAL As Double
    Dim i, j, col As Integer
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim NAME As Long
    Dim WSHTNAME As Variant
    Dim ABC As String
    Dim yrs As Integer


    'DEFINING PATH
    PATH = Cells(18, 11).Text
    PATH1 = Cells(19, 11).Text
    PATH3 = PATH1 & "\Large Claim_Output_Extended.XLSX"
    PATH4 = Cells(23, 11).Text

    Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(PATH3)

    Workbooks.Add

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PATH1 & "Large Claim Monthly Triangle.XLSX"

    'FOR MOTOR TAB
    WSHTNAME = Array("PMPCOD", "CMOD", "PMMCOD", "PMPCTBI", "CMTBI", "PMMCTBI", "PMPCTPD", "PMMCTPD", "CMTPD")

    For NAME = LBound(WSHTNAME) To UBound(WSHTNAME)
        With objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME))

            'CHANGE WS NAME HERE'
            Set WS2 = Sheets.Add

            'CAPTURE DATA
            If WSHTNAME(NAME) = "PMMCOD" Then
                col = Application.Match("GINC_OD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                col_n = Application.Match("NINC_OD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                colp = Application.Match("GODP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                colp_n = Application.Match("NODP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                coltb_n = Application.Match("OD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                coltlc_n = Application.Match("TOD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)

                ElseIf WSHTNAME(NAME) = "PMPCOD" Then
                    col = Application.Match("GINC_OD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    col_n = Application.Match("NINC_OD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp = Application.Match("GODP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp_n = Application.Match("NODP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltb_n = Application.Match("OD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltlc_n = Application.Match("TOD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)

                ElseIf WSHTNAME(NAME) = "CMOD" Then
                    col = Application.Match("GINC_OD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    col_n = Application.Match("NINC_OD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp = Application.Match("GODP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp_n = Application.Match("NODP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltb_n = Application.Match("OD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltlc_n = Application.Match("TOD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)

                ElseIf WSHTNAME(NAME) = "PMMCTBI" Then
                    col = Application.Match("GINC_TB1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    col_n = Application.Match("NINC_TB1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp = Application.Match("GTBP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp_n = Application.Match("NTBP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltb_n = Application.Match("TB_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltlc_n = Application.Match("TTB_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)

                ElseIf WSHTNAME(NAME) = "PMPCTBI" Then
                    col = Application.Match("GINC_TB1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    col_n = Application.Match("NINC_TB1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp = Application.Match("GTBP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp_n = Application.Match("NTBP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltb_n = Application.Match("TB_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltlc_n = Application.Match("TTB_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)

                ElseIf WSHTNAME(NAME) = "CMTBI" Then
                    col = Application.Match("GINC_TB1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    col_n = Application.Match("NINC_TB1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp = Application.Match("GTBP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp_n = Application.Match("NTBP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltb_n = Application.Match("TB_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltlc_n = Application.Match("TTB_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)

                ElseIf WSHTNAME(NAME) = "CMTPD" Then
                    col = Application.Match("GINC_TD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    col_n = Application.Match("NINC_TD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp = Application.Match("GTDP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp_n = Application.Match("NTDP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltb_n = Application.Match("TD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltlc_n = Application.Match("TTD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)

                ElseIf WSHTNAME(NAME) = "PMPCTPD" Then
                    col = Application.Match("GINC_TD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    col_n = Application.Match("NINC_TD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp = Application.Match("GTDP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp_n = Application.Match("NTDP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltb_n = Application.Match("TD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltlc_n = Application.Match("TTD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)

                ElseIf WSHTNAME(NAME) = "PMMCTPD" Then
                    col = Application.Match("GINC_TD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    col_n = Application.Match("NINC_TD1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp = Application.Match("GTDP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp_n = Application.Match("NTDP1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltb_n = Application.Match("TD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltlc_n = Application.Match("TTD_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)

                Else
                    col = Application.Match("GINC01", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    col_n = Application.Match("NINC01", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp = Application.Match("GPAY01", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    colp_n = Application.Match("NPAY01", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltb_n = Application.Match("PA_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
                    coltlc_n = Application.Match("TPA_L1", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
            End If

            ABC = WSHTNAME(NAME)
            AOCCURYR = Application.Match("AOCCURYR", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
            ACCTYEAR = Application.Match("ACCTYEAR", objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)


            Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            lRowCount = objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).UsedRange.Rows.Count
            lColumnCount = objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).UsedRange.Columns.Count


            WS2.NAME = ABC

            'INSERT TITLE
            WS2.Cells(2, 1).Value = "GROSS INCURRED"
            WS2.Cells(23, 1).Value = "GROSS PAID"
            WS2.Cells(44, 1).Value = "NET INCURRED"
            WS2.Cells(65, 1).Value = "NET PAID"
            WS2.Cells(86, 1).Value = "CLAIM COUNT"
            WS2.Cells(107, 1).Value = "CLAIM COUNT(THRESHOLD)"

            yrsmax = Workbooks(PATH4).Worksheets("SHEET1").Cells(17, 13).Value
            yrsmin = Workbooks(PATH4).Worksheets("SHEET1").Cells(17, 11).Value


            'GROSS INCURRED
            For d = 0 To 14
                cumulative1 = 0
                cumulative2 = 0
                cumulative3 = 0
                cumulative4 = 0
                cumulative5 = 0
                cumulative6 = 0
                cumulative7 = 0
                cumulative8 = 0
                cumulative9 = 0
                cumulative10 = 0
                cumulative11 = 0
                cumulative12 = 0
                For j = 1 To lColumnCount - 1
                    If objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells.Value >= 500000 Then
                        For i = 1 To lRowCount - 1
                            If objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, AOCCURYR).Value <= yrsmax - 14 Then
                                acct = objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, ACCTYEAR).Value - objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, AOCCURYR).Value
                                    If acct = d Then
                                        cumulative1 = cumulative1 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col).Value
                                        cumulative2 = cumulative2 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 1).Value
                                        cumulative3 = cumulative3 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 2).Value
                                        cumulative4 = cumulative4 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 3).Value
                                        cumulative5 = cumulative5 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 4).Value
                                        cumulative6 = cumulative6 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 5).Value
                                        cumulative7 = cumulative7 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 6).Value
                                        cumulative8 = cumulative8 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 7).Value
                                        cumulative9 = cumulative9 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 8).Value
                                        cumulative10 = cumulative10 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 9).Value
                                        cumulative11 = cumulative11 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 10).Value
                                        cumulative12 = cumulative12 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 11).Value
                                    End If
                            End If
                        Next i

                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 2).Value = cumulative1
                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 3).Value = cumulative2
                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 4).Value = cumulative3
                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 5).Value = cumulative4
                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 6).Value = cumulative5
                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 7).Value = cumulative6
                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 8).Value = cumulative7
                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 9).Value = cumulative8
                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 10).Value = cumulative9
                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 11).Value = cumulative10
                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 12).Value = cumulative11
                        WS2.Cells(4, 12 * (d) + 13).Value = cumulative12
                    End If
                Next j
            Next d

            For j = yrsmax - 13 To yrsmax
                For d = j To yrsmax
                    cumulative1 = 0
                    cumulative2 = 0
                    cumulative3 = 0
                    cumulative4 = 0
                    cumulative5 = 0
                    cumulative6 = 0
                    cumulative7 = 0
                    cumulative8 = 0
                    cumulative9 = 0
                    cumulative10 = 0
                    cumulative11 = 0
                    cumulative12 = 0

                    For i = 1 To lRowCount - 1
                        acct = objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, AOCCURYR).Value & objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, ACCTYEAR).Value

                        If acct = j & d Then
                            cumulative1 = cumulative1 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col).Value
                            cumulative2 = cumulative2 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 1).Value
                            cumulative3 = cumulative3 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 2).Value
                            cumulative4 = cumulative4 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 3).Value
                            cumulative5 = cumulative5 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 4).Value
                            cumulative6 = cumulative6 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 5).Value
                            cumulative7 = cumulative7 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 6).Value
                            cumulative8 = cumulative8 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 7).Value
                            cumulative9 = cumulative9 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 8).Value
                            cumulative10 = cumulative10 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 9).Value
                            cumulative11 = cumulative11 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 10).Value
                            cumulative12 = cumulative12 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col + 11).Value
                        End If
                    Next i
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 2).Value = cumulative1
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 3).Value = cumulative2
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 4).Value = cumulative3
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 5).Value = cumulative4
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 6).Value = cumulative5
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 7).Value = cumulative6
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 8).Value = cumulative7
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 9).Value = cumulative8
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 10).Value = cumulative9
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 11).Value = cumulative10
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 12).Value = cumulative11
                    WS2.Cells(3 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 13).Value = cumulative12
                Next d
            Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

part 2 (as code is over 30,000 characters)

```
            For i = yrsmax - 13 To yrsmax
                WS2.Cells(4, 1).Value = (yrsmax - 14) & "&prior"
                WS2.Cells(3 + i - yrsmin + 1, 1).Value = i
            Next i

            For i = 1 To 180
                WS2.Cells(3, i + 1).Value = i
            Next i

            'PAID'
            For d = 0 To 14
                cumulative1 = 0
                cumulative2 = 0
                cumulative3 = 0
                cumulative4 = 0
                cumulative5 = 0
                cumulative6 = 0
                cumulative7 = 0
                cumulative8 = 0
                cumulative9 = 0
                cumulative10 = 0
                cumulative11 = 0
                cumulative12 = 0

                For i = 1 To lRowCount - 1
                    If objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, AOCCURYR).Value <= yrsmax - 14 Then
                        acct = objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, ACCTYEAR).Value - objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, AOCCURYR).Value
                        If acct = d Then
                            cumulative1 = cumulative1 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp).Value
                            cumulative2 = cumulative2 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 1).Value
                            cumulative3 = cumulative3 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 2).Value
                            cumulative4 = cumulative4 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 3).Value
                            cumulative5 = cumulative5 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 4).Value
                            cumulative6 = cumulative6 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 5).Value
                            cumulative7 = cumulative7 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 6).Value
                            cumulative8 = cumulative8 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 7).Value
                            cumulative9 = cumulative9 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 8).Value
                            cumulative10 = cumulative10 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 9).Value
                            cumulative11 = cumulative11 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 10).Value
                            cumulative12 = cumulative12 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 11).Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next i

                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 2).Value = cumulative1
                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 3).Value = cumulative2
                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 4).Value = cumulative3
                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 5).Value = cumulative4
                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 6).Value = cumulative5
                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 7).Value = cumulative6
                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 8).Value = cumulative7
                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 9).Value = cumulative8
                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 10).Value = cumulative9
                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 11).Value = cumulative10
                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 12).Value = cumulative11
                WS2.Cells(25, 12 * (d) + 13).Value = cumulative12
            Next d

            For j = yrsmax - 13 To yrsmax
                For d = j To yrsmax
                    cumulative1 = 0
                    cumulative2 = 0
                    cumulative3 = 0
                    cumulative4 = 0
                    cumulative5 = 0
                    cumulative6 = 0
                    cumulative7 = 0
                    cumulative8 = 0
                    cumulative9 = 0
                    cumulative10 = 0
                    cumulative11 = 0
                    cumulative12 = 0
                        For i = 1 To lRowCount - 1
                            acct = objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, AOCCURYR).Value & objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, ACCTYEAR).Value
                            If acct = j & d Then
                                cumulative1 = cumulative1 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp).Value
                                cumulative2 = cumulative2 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 1).Value
                                cumulative3 = cumulative3 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 2).Value
                                cumulative4 = cumulative4 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 3).Value
                                cumulative5 = cumulative5 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 4).Value
                                cumulative6 = cumulative6 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 5).Value
                                cumulative7 = cumulative7 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 6).Value
                                cumulative8 = cumulative8 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 7).Value
                                cumulative9 = cumulative9 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 8).Value
                                cumulative10 = cumulative10 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 9).Value
                                cumulative11 = cumulative11 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 10).Value
                                cumulative12 = cumulative12 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, colp + 11).Value
                            End If
                        Next i
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 2).Value = cumulative1
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 3).Value = cumulative2
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 4).Value = cumulative3
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 5).Value = cumulative4
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 6).Value = cumulative5
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 7).Value = cumulative6
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 8).Value = cumulative7
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 9).Value = cumulative8
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 10).Value = cumulative9
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 11).Value = cumulative10
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 12).Value = cumulative11
                        WS2.Cells(24 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 13).Value = cumulative12
                Next d
            Next j

            For i = yrsmax - 13 To yrsmax
                WS2.Cells(25, 1).Value = (yrsmax - 14) & "&prior"
                WS2.Cells(24 + i - yrsmin + 1, 1).Value = i
            Next i

            For i = 1 To 180
                WS2.Cells(24, i + 1).Value = i
            Next i

            'NET INCURRED
            For d = 0 To 14
                cumulative1 = 0
                cumulative2 = 0
                cumulative3 = 0
                cumulative4 = 0
                cumulative5 = 0
                cumulative6 = 0
                cumulative7 = 0
                cumulative8 = 0
                cumulative9 = 0
                cumulative10 = 0
                cumulative11 = 0
                cumulative12 = 0
                For i = 1 To lRowCount - 1
                    If objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, AOCCURYR).Value <= yrsmax - 14 Then
                    acct = objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, ACCTYEAR).Value - objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, AOCCURYR).Value
                        If acct = d Then
                            cumulative1 = cumulative1 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n).Value
                            cumulative2 = cumulative2 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 1).Value
                            cumulative3 = cumulative3 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 2).Value
                            cumulative4 = cumulative4 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 3).Value
                            cumulative5 = cumulative5 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 4).Value
                            cumulative6 = cumulative6 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 5).Value
                            cumulative7 = cumulative7 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 6).Value
                            cumulative8 = cumulative8 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 7).Value
                            cumulative9 = cumulative9 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 8).Value
                            cumulative10 = cumulative10 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 9).Value
                            cumulative11 = cumulative11 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 10).Value
                            cumulative12 = cumulative12 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 11).Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next i
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 2).Value = cumulative1
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 3).Value = cumulative2
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 4).Value = cumulative3
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 5).Value = cumulative4
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 6).Value = cumulative5
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 7).Value = cumulative6
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 8).Value = cumulative7
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 9).Value = cumulative8
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 10).Value = cumulative9
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 11).Value = cumulative10
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 12).Value = cumulative11
                WS2.Cells(46, 12 * (d) + 13).Value = cumulative12
            Next d

            For j = yrsmax - 13 To yrsmax
                For d = j To yrsmax
                    cumulative1 = 0
                    cumulative2 = 0
                    cumulative3 = 0
                    cumulative4 = 0
                    cumulative5 = 0
                    cumulative6 = 0
                    cumulative7 = 0
                    cumulative8 = 0
                    cumulative9 = 0
                    cumulative10 = 0
                    cumulative11 = 0
                    cumulative12 = 0

                    For i = 1 To lRowCount - 1
                        acct = objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, AOCCURYR).Value & objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, ACCTYEAR).Value
                        If acct = j & d Then
                            cumulative1 = cumulative1 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n).Value
                            cumulative2 = cumulative2 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 1).Value
                            cumulative3 = cumulative3 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 2).Value
                            cumulative4 = cumulative4 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 3).Value
                            cumulative5 = cumulative5 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 4).Value
                            cumulative6 = cumulative6 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 5).Value
                            cumulative7 = cumulative7 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 6).Value
                            cumulative8 = cumulative8 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 7).Value
                            cumulative9 = cumulative9 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 8).Value
                            cumulative10 = cumulative10 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 9).Value
                            cumulative11 = cumulative11 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 10).Value
                            cumulative12 = cumulative12 + objWorkbook.Worksheets(WSHTNAME(NAME)).Cells(1 + i, col_n + 11).Value
                        End If
                    Next i
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 2).Value = cumulative1
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 3).Value = cumulative2
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 4).Value = cumulative3
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 5).Value = cumulative4
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 6).Value = cumulative5
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 7).Value = cumulative6
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 8).Value = cumulative7
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 9).Value = cumulative8
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 10).Value = cumulative9
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 11).Value = cumulative10
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 12).Value = cumulative11
                    WS2.Cells(45 + j - yrsmin + 1, 12 * (d - j) + 13).Value = cumulative12
                Next d
            Next j

            For i = yrsmax - 13 To yrsmax
                WS2.Cells(46, 1).Value = (yrsmax - 14) & "&prior"
                WS2.Cells(45 + i - yrsmin + 1, 1).Value = i
            Next i

            For i = 1 To 180
                WS2.Cells(45, i + 1).Value = i
            Next i

        End With
    Next NAME

    'Rearrange Worksheets
    Sheets("PMPCTBI").Move before:=Sheets(1)
    Sheets("PMPCTPD").Move before:=Sheets(2)
    Sheets("PMPCOD").Move before:=Sheets(3)
    Sheets("PMMCOD").Move before:=Sheets(4)
    Sheets("PMMCTBI").Move before:=Sheets(5)
    Sheets("PMMCOD").Move before:=Sheets(6)
    Sheets("CMTBI").Move before:=Sheets(7)
    Sheets("CMTPD").Move before:=Sheets(8)
    Sheets("CMOD").Move before:=Sheets(9)

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PATH1 & "\Large Claim Monthly Triangle_Motor.xlsx"


End Sub
```